If an effect that triggers when a card is returned to the hand work when a card is returned to the extra deck?
The specific Scenario that prompted the question was dragonmaid downtime and House Dragon Maid on master duel, where downtime effect says "return[the 'Dragonmaid' monster] to the hand, and if you do, add 1 'Dragonmaid' card from your deck to you hand" when I choose House Dragonmaid she was returned to the extra deck but I wasn't granted a card from the deck

The extra deck is not the hand. Why would we expect it to be treated as such, in the absence of something saying it should be?

The reason I thought it would is because the effect says to "return it to the hand" and not "return it to the extra deck"

The effect is irrelevant both ways. 1: rules say a card from extra desk goes back to extra deck, and 2: it just did not go back to the hand at all.

As mentioned in comments, an extra deck monster cannot go to the hand or to the main deck. If such effect affect an extra deck monster, it is sent back to the extra deck instead by the rules.
Let's take the effect of "Dragonmaid Downtime" used in this scenario:

Return it to the hand, and if you do, add 1 "Dragonmaid" card from your Deck to your hand, except "Dragonmaid Downtime".

If you target "House Dragonmaid" with "Dragonmaid Downtime", the effect "Return it to the hand" will send it back to the extra deck instead. However, as it was sent to the extra deck and not to the hand, the next part "add 1 "Dragonmaid" card from your Deck to your hand" doesn't apply, as the card says "and if you do".
